# Error performing segue that was working correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a problem with an app I am developing. In one of the controllers, whenever I try to press a button that performs a segue the app crashes (if it's programmatically added with "has no segue with identifier 'showBlog'" error) or just doesn't work (when it's a cntrl + drag added segue with "Terminated due to signal 9" error). I have double checked and the segue identifiers are correctly added. They where corking previously and now they stopped. I have already closed Xcode and restarted the computer, also cleaned and rebuild the app.

**What have I changed since last time it worked?**

I added an alert when the user presses another button (that it's working correctly) also, I tried to copy a button (cntrl + c) but by mistake I made the copy selecting the full view controller and when I made the paste (cntrl + v) nothing happened that I can see, but I guess that might be the problem.  But I can't find any view controller to erase. Any ideas on how to correct this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Delete the view and the controller make a new one and try it**.. it's a glitch sometimes in the Xcode..

Let me know if it works thanks :)